# change scale of the datatype Number from 0 to 14 in snowflake?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column in my snowflake database having datatype -
Number(38,0). I want to change it to Number( 38, 14 ) .

**datatype format - Number( precision , scale)**

I know that snowflake does not allow changing the scale of the Number datatype.
hence, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

the column type changing is not supported in Snowflake, you can do the following steps.

```
create table tab1 (fld1 Number(38,0));
insert into tab1 values (12.2);
select * from tab1;

alter table tab1 alter column fld1 Number(38,14);
-- QL compilation error: cannot change column FLD1 from type NUMBER(38,0) to NUMBER(38,14)
because changing the scale of a number is not supported.

alter table tab1 add column fld2 Number(38,14);
update tab1 set fld2 = fld1;
alter table tab1 drop column fld1;
alter table tab1 rename column fld2 to fld1;
```

Comment: thank you so much @Himanshu for this. Though, is there any other way to do this cause the columns are being currently used downstream for different processing.

Comment: is there a way to type cast the datatypes? like                                          
      Number(38,0) -> Varchar/ float / decimal -> Number(38,14)

Comment: incorrect.. snowflake allows changing precision, only scale is not allowed.

so for scale workaround:
`alter table t add column v number(20, 3);
update t set v= old_col_19_2;
alter table t drop column old_col_19_2;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CTAS syntax for this:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE (COL1 NUMBER(38,0));
    
    INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE VALUES (38);

    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE (COL1 NUMBER(38,14))
    AS 
    SELECT COL1 FROM SAMPLE_TABLE; 

    SELECT COL1 FROM SAMPLE_TABLE;
```

Ref: [CREATE TABLE … AS SELECT (also referred to as CTAS)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax)